# Acer LED monitor(V176L) showing that input not supported

Tags: multiple-monitors, external-display, acer-aspire

I've attached an Acer LED monitor(V176L) to my Dell laptop (Inspiron 15-7579) via a VGA to HDMI converter. My laptop is running fine with windows 10. But when I set the “double” display, the 2nd screen (Acer monitor) shows "Input not supported". Acer monitor only works when I set the “extend” display, but it is not working in the “double” display. My current resolution is 1920X1080. I changed it to 1680x1050 & 1600x900 but still, the Acer monitor shows that “Input Not Supported”. Is there an easy way to solve this problem? Thank you